# Adding a index to collection using EF 4.1 and XAML (For a highscore table)

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, entity-framework-4

I have a webservice I call from a WP7 app. I get a list of high scores in a table (name/score).. What is the simpliest way to add a 3rd column on the far left which is simply the row?

Do I need to add a property to the entity? Is there someway to get the row #?

I tried these things below with no success..

```
 [OperationContract]
    public List<DMHighScore> GetScores()
    {
        using (var db = new DMModelContainer())
        {
            //  return db.DMHighScores.ToList();

            var collOrderedHighScoreItem = (from o in db.DMHighScores
                                            orderby o.UserScore ascending
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                o.UserName,
                                                o.UserScore
                                            }).Take(20);


            var collOrderedHighScoreItem2 = collOrderedHighScoreItem.AsEnumerable().Select((x, i) => new DMHighScoreDTO
            {
                UserName = x.UserName,
                UserScore = x.UserScore
            }).ToList();



        }


    }
  [DataContract]
public class DMHighScoreDTO
{
    int Rank;
    string UserName;
    string UserScore;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets assume you want to load top 100 users in leaderboard and you want to have their rank included:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<ScoreDto> GetTop100()
{
    // Linq to entities query
    var query = (from u from context.Users
                 order by u.Score
                 select new 
                     {
                         u.Name,
                         u.Score
                     }).Take(100);

    // Linq to objects query from working on 100 records loaded from DB
    // Select with index doesn't work in linq to entities
    var data = query.AsEnumerable().Select((x, i) => new ScoreDto
        {
            Rank = i + 1,
            Name = x.Name,
            Score = x.Score
        }).ToList();

    return data;
 }
```

Comment: I tihnk  Iam close...  Where would you define ScoreDto ?   I have trouble defining that and getting my webservice to see it  Error 2 'PunkouterSoftware.WCF.DMHighScoreDTO.UserName' is inaccessible due to its protection level C:\_Code\_PunkouterSoftware\PunkouterSoftware\WCF\DMHighScoreService.svc.cs 42 21 PunkouterSoftware

Comment: `ScoreDto` should be data contract and it must have all properties public with getter and setter.

Comment: got it to work thanks...  though would it not be easier to use linq projection and project into a anonomous type?  though I guess I couldnt do that in the web service.. but I could do that on the client side

Comment: You can't use anonymous types as return value from method.

Answer (score 1):

what will the row number be used for? if this is for ordering might I suggest adding a column named Order, then map the column to your entity.

if you require a row index, you could also call the .ToList() on the query and fetch the index locations for each entity.

Edit:

you could add the Rank property and set it to Ignore. This will enable you to go through the collection set the rank with a simple for loop. This will also not be persisted in the database. It will also not have any required columns in the database.

It does add an extra iteration.

the other way to go about it. This would be to add the rank number in the generated UI and not in the data collection being used to bind.

Comment: Its simply to have a number 1 to 10 from the top to bottom... I will try your idea of th etolist and look for a 'index location'